# Create a line break in the text inside span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the following HTML in the application:-

```
<span style="display:inline-block;white-space: pre-line">I would like to discuss this: {"incidentId":"TG00040","desc":"Patient Details","reportdetails":"Patient Name:Bhawana \n Grade:10th \n Teacher:Meeta"}</span>
```

But am not able to create line breaks in the text. I have also tried using \n,\r and br tag but nothing seems to break. The expected output is:-

I would like to discuss this: {"incidentId":"TG00040","desc":"Patient Details","reportdetails":"Patient Name:Bhawana 
 Grade:10th 
 Teacher:Meeta"}

Comment: please share your expected output

Comment: The content within the curly braces are not standard html nor javascript. What kind of javascript du you use?

Comment: A `<br>` tag works fine for me, what exactly are you trying to achieve and how is it not working?

Comment: for line break use `<br>` tag instead of `\n`

Comment: Have tried but does not works in the actual code

Comment: what you have tried? share here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<br>` instead of `\n`. Do you want output like this with a line break?

```html
<span style="display:inline-block;white-space: pre-line">I would like to discuss this: {"incidentId":"TG00040","desc":"Patient Details","reportdetails":"Patient Name:Bhawana <br> Grade:10th <br> Teacher:Meeta"}</span>
```

Comment: The output is correct . But it does not works in the web app that I am working on

Comment: which web app you have used? and share more detail about it.

Answer (score 1):

If data displayed in span contain the character `\n` and you can't modify it before display it in dom

you can use a simple js function to replace all `\n` occurence by `<br/>`

```js
var span = document.getElementById('my-data');
span.innerHTML = span.innerHTML.replaceAll('\\n', '<br/>');
```

```html
<span id="my-data">I would like to discuss this: {"incidentId":"TG00040","desc":"Patient Details","reportdetails":"Patient Name:Bhawana \n Grade:10th \n Teacher:Meeta"}</span>
```

just be careful to mastered dom modification when you replace innerHTML. here there is no risk but if you have based replace on user input you can have xss issue

Comment: add more detail to your answer. so other users will see what was exact change

Comment: added details to my reply. I expect it explain difference with other one